# How to properly clear ngx-material-file-input for detecting changes when same file is uploaded twice

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material 6.4.7 and [merlosy/ngx-material-file-input](https://github.com/merlosy/ngx-material-file-input/) version 0.3.1. In one of my pages I have a ngx-mat-file-input. Each time a file is selected I do something with the file and then I reset the input. For this, I subscribe to the valueChange event of the control asociated to the input. The problem is that if the same file is uploaded twice in a row the valueChange event doesn't fire in Chrome and Explorer/Edge (It does in Firefox).

I tried to reset the input value using:

```
this.form.control['file'].reset();
this.form.control['file'].setValue(null);
this.form.control['file'].setValue('');
this.form.control['file'].setValue([]);
```

inside the valueChange event after treating the file but Chrome and Explorer still don't detect the change.

Here is the fragment of my typescript file:

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
  file: []
})

this.form.controls['file'].valueChanges.subscribe(
  file => {
    if (file != null && typeof file != undefined && file != '') {
      alert('changed!');
      this.form.controls['file'].reset();
    }
  }
)
```

You can see how this work in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-material-file-input-831jgy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've figured out a solution that works in all browsers. I just have to get the `<input>` element that is generated and reset it's value:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  file: []
})

this.form.controls['file'].valueChanges.subscribe(
  file => {
    if (file != null && typeof file != undefined) {
      alert('changed!');
      this.form.controls['file'].setValue(null, { emitEvent: false });
      const fileInput = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('ngx-mat-file-input[formcontrolname="file"] input[type="file"]');
      fileInput.value = null;
    }
  }
)
```

Here is the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-material-file-input-yk1muf)